# topology sources

Tags: general-topology

I am looking for topology pdfs for someone who is completely new in the subject, I'd like it to contain lots of examples, detailed proofs and exercises with solutions. Do you have something to recommend?

Comment: Not a PDF, but I would highly recommend Munkres' introductory book on the subject.

Comment: Apart from not having solutions for the exercises (arguably not that helpful anyway), [Topology without Tears](https://www.topologywithouttears.net/) would be a good fit.